# How to resolve entity Framework not picking up manual data changes in the DB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

We are manually updating the data in Database but it's not refelecting immediatley in UI.
Please tell me how to get the updated data in entity framework ?
I saw some of the forums, refresh method will reflect the updated changes in entity framework.
is it right way or any suggestions let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh the entity or try by adding a property to the entity in your EF model, and then map the property to the database column

Comment: In repository wrote the Read,update and delete methods.By using refresh method i am updating my entities.But some time in my code the results are returing as table property.Don't know how to refresh the properties of a class not calling any read operation directly as class property returning the results.How to refresh the class property to get latest records?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ does not update the table changes in these situations: RUD - Read, Update, Delete
Witch means, only Insert (new rows) will update the cache

If you changed (updated) a row using SSMS, then LINQ will not detect this change
If you insert a new row, then it will

To "fix" it, you need to call the Refresh method before each RUD (if necessary, only)

something like: mydb.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, mydb.MyCustomerTable);

this will force LINQ to update the cache